# Drawing line from sprite with a touch

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am working with cocos2d for the iPhone and I have a question about how to implement the following. I have a circle shaped sprite on my layer. When I touch the sprite  and move my finger a line must be drawn from the sprite to where my finger is. When I move my finger on the screen the line must follow (straight line). When I release my finger the line should disappear. In a good looking way I should be able to restyle the line into an arrow.

Can anyone move me in the right direction for this ?

Kind regards

Comment: And what have you done already?

Comment: hello,well beside adding the 2 sprites on the layer not much. I have read about the CCDrawLine method but I can't connect to how I can use it with the thing I need. A wild guess would be to keep track on the startpoint and updating the endpoint and draw method as long as you keep the touch but I don't know if that's the right way.

Comment: @Kaizer Sounds like the right way. Why don't you try it?

Comment: you can see this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749853/draw-a-line-sprite-between-two-points-made-by-sprites-in-cocos2d

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this. Just store the start touch location on ccTouchesBegan, store you end point on ccTouchesMoved and then draw lines in the draw method between the 2 stored points.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CCMotionStreak](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCMotionStreak.html) to achieve a nice fade effect for your line. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yfwjyyGtXg4) is how CCMotionStreak looks like.

If you want a simple line, without any fancy effects, then you can use the method `[drawSegmentFrom]` of [CCDrawNode](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCDrawNode.html).